# Navigate to another ContentPage from async method before the async method returns a value

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await, content-pages

I need to start Another ContentPage before this async method returns value:

```
public class GettingCountry : ContentPage
{
    public static List<string> CountriesList = new List<string>();

    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
    public async Task<List<RootObject>> FetchAsync(string url)
    {
        string jsonString;
        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var listOfCountries = new List<RootObject>();

        var responseCountries = JArray.Parse(JObject.Parse(jsonString)["response"]["items"].ToString());

        foreach (var countryInResponse in responseCountries)
        {
            var rootObject = new RootObject((int)countryInResponse["id"], (string)countryInResponse["title"]);

            CountriesList.Add(rootObject.Title);
        }

        //I NEED TO NAVIGATE TO FillingPage() FROM HERE:
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new FillingPage());

        //await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new FillingPage()));

        return listOfCountries;
    }
```

The page that is need to be started is:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class FillingPage : ContentPage
{
    public FillingPage ()
    {
        GettingCountry gettingCountry = new GettingCountry();

        Label header = new Label
        {
            Text = "Заполните бланк",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            TextColor = Color.Blue
        };

        Entry nameEntry = new Entry()
        {
            Placeholder = "Имя",
        };

        Entry surnameEntry = new Entry()
        {
            Placeholder = "Фамилия"
        };

        Picker countryPicker = new Picker()
        {
            Title = "Страна",
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        foreach (string country in GettingCountry.CountriesList)
        {
            countryPicker.Items.Add(country);
        }

        SearchBar townSearchBar = new SearchBar()
        {
            Placeholder = "Город",
            SearchCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
            })
        };

        SearchBar universitySearchBar = new SearchBar()
        {
            Placeholder = "Университет",
            SearchCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
            })
        };
        Button myButton = new Button()
       {
           TextColor = Color.Green,
           Text = "Выполнить",
           FontSize = 22
       };

        // Accomodate iPhone status bar.
        this.Padding = new Thickness(10, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 10, 5);

        // Build the page.
        this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                header,
                nameEntry,
                surnameEntry,
                countryPicker,
                townSearchBar,
                universitySearchBar,
                myButton
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

But this code `await Navigation.PushAsync(new FillingPage());` works well only when I press a button. When I press a button the needed page starts well. But the same code inside a method does not work. I have debagged it. It goes to a `FillingPage()` but doesn`t launches it when I try to launch it from inside the async method.

Comment: Just a couple for comments, completely unrelated to your question. You can use `httpClient.GetStringAsync()` to get the string directly. And it's more performant not to dispose the `HttpClient`. In the background it's a shared instance between all requests, and disposing it creates more overhead. See here for details: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a result of the operation not being performed on the main thread. Try wrapping your code like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new FillingPage());
}
```

**Edit:** After a private message, I learned that there was not enough information in the question to know the real issue. The application is calling `FetchAsync` in `Application.OnStart` and it's not part of the view hiearchy at all so navigation methods would not work. The following was provided:

```
protected override void OnStart ()
{
    getCountry();
}

private async void getCountry()
{
    var url = "...";
    GettingCountry gettingCountry = new GettingCountry();
    await gettingCountry.FetchAsync(url);
}
```

`GettingCountry` is a `ContentPage` being used like some kind of data access class and it's not currently part of the UI as `MainPage` is set to something else. A quick hack would be something more like:

```
private async void getCountry()
{
    var url = "...";
    GettingCountry gettingCountry = new GettingCountry();
    var data = await gettingCountry.FetchAsync(url);
    await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FillingPage(data));
 }
```

I would suggest two further areas to look at improving.

1. Consider refactoring `GettingCountry` as it does not need to be a `ContentPage`.
2. Investigate an alternative calling so that `async void` is not used.

Comment: Why the downvote? What could I do to improve the answer?

Comment: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread was the answer I needed. I was trying to change the MainPage on an async thread. Doing it on the UI/Main thread was what I should have been doing. A lesson I wont soon forget.